# Manually set rows affected in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

We have stored procedures that are executed in code via non-query through the MySql.Data .net client. The issue is: in some procedures we want to "log" some information into a database table in conjunction with performing an insert, update, or delete. If we perform the logging prior to the insert, update, or delete (which is done by calling another stored procedure) then we end up with inaccurate logs if the insert, update, or delete fails or affects no rows. If we perform the logging after the insert, update, or delete then the rows affected by the stored procedure are the number of rows affected by the logging call, and not the number of rows affected by the insert, update, or delete.

I'm aware that I can use `row_count()` to get the number of rows affected by the insert, update, or delete... but is it possible to the perform some conditional logic and logging afterwards THEN set the number of rows affected "manually" prior to exiting the procedure? I know I can just return the number, but then I would have to change all of the application code to execute a scalar query instead of a non-query. It would be much more preferable to only have to alter the stored procedures and not have to alter/redeploy the actual applications.

Comment: Could you perform your logging via a trigger? I don't think rows are included in the row count there.

Comment: Probably a good idea, but I don't think it will work for this. The stored procedures take in some additional parameters we'd want to log that wouldn't be included in a trigger of a table's data change. We'd also probably need to write 50+ triggers which would have a lot of conditional logic depending on what specific columns are changing. Also, I don't have a ton of mysql experience (postgres, mssql, oracle), so I don't know if this is true or not, but a colleague here is very against mysql triggers because he claims they have significant performance impact.

Comment: Yes I would agree trigger usage should be mininal and specific and not somewhere you'd normally have business logic, but your requirement has limited resolutions.

Comment: Check out Auditing plugins and/or MariaDB's automatic logging.